# cannot pip install pipenv on Windows

Tags: pip

Hi I have Python3 and I am trying to install pipenv on Windows.

I use `pip install pipenv` but  this is the output:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001A95B3C02D0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pipenv/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001A95E542490>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pipenv/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001A95E54D390>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pipenv/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001A95E54F510>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pipenv/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001A95E568190>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pipenv/ ERROR: Could not
> find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions:
> none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv

I try this command too `pip install --upgrade pip` and get this

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\dev\python\lib\site-packages
> (22.3.1) WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000002383EC3F3D0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000002383EC331D0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000002383EC3D3D0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000002383EC3F850>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000002383EC58490>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/ WARNING: There was
> an error checking the latest version of pip.

This is my pip version: pip 22.3.1 from C:\myFolder\python\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

I am on a corporate proxy.

Comment: Seems like network issues to me, so probably nothing that we can help with here on StackOverflow, it is out of scope. -- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pip+WARNING+Retrying

Comment: `getaddrinfo failed` is your local DNS problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pip can't send a request to its URL.

Try running `pip install pipenv -vvv` and see more information about what error it raises.

Could you also run `pip config list` to see the current configuration of pip?
When you run `pip config list` and if the value of `global.index-url` is not `https://pypi.python.org/simple/`, please run `pip config set global.index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/` and it should solve the problem.